# Regex to validate a numeric submission-

Tags: regex

So... the question is how do you deal with an empty value and format? I would need to handle the following range:

0-120.00

So I'm thinking the regex would be the following or something similar-

```
[\d][\d][\d]\.[\d][\d]
```

How can you accommodate the movement of the decimal and the possibility of empty spaces?

Also please forgive the noob question in advance... I'm just trying to learn it though so any links or sites would be appreciated. I have found this playground so far http://regexpal.com/

Comment: What does it mean moving of decimal and empty spaces? You need to provide more examples.

Comment: `^(?:\d{1,2}(?:\.\d{1,2})?|1[0-1]\d(?:\.\d{1,2})?|120(?:\.0{1,2})?)$`

Comment: "Empty spaces" ? Its a little hard to deal with the range with space(s) imbeded isin't it? Why not just `^[ \d.]+$` for validation of proper characters, then convert it to a float that can be checked for range, in the language that you use the regex engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is just fine for this, but the expression you need depends on your requirements:

There is a value range verification (`0`-`120`), and then formatting verification (optional `.` with numbers after it), but the biggest question (about your requirements) is what you expect for decimal places - do you want to restrict it to only 2 decimal places?

if you want to restrict to two decimal places, then use this:

```
^((\d\d?|1[01]\d)(\.\d{1,2})?|120(\.0{1,2})?)$
```

if you want to allow any number of digits after the decimal, you just change the `{1,2}` (which means one or two repetitions) into `+` (which is short hand for one or more repetitions), like this:

```
^((\d\d?|1[01]\d)(\.\d+)?|120(\.0+)?)$
```

these break down like this:

```
^            # Assert at the beginning
(            # THEN Match the following as a group:     (main grouping)
   (         #    Match the following as a group:       (this is possibility #1)
      \d     #       a single digit
      \d?    #       then an optional single digit
       |     #        -OR-
      1      #       a '1'
      [01]   #       then either a '0' or a '1'
      \d     #       then any digit
   )         #    <end group>
   (         #    THEN Match the following as a group:
      \.     #       a literal '.' (period)
      \d+    #       then one or more digits
   )?        #    <end group> (optional group)

    |        #     -OR-

   120       #    the literal characters '120'          (this is possibility #2)
   (         #    THEN Match the following:
      \.     #       a literal '.' (period)
      0+     #       then one or more zeros
   )?        #    <end group> (optional group)
)            # <end main group>
$            # Assert at the end
```

When you group something, it has to be matched as a group - basically all or nothing.there are two possibilities (one of which contains twoo "sub"-possibilities itself) theres the part that handles numbers `0`-`119.99` and the part that handles `120.00`. The distinction here is that `120` cannot have anything but `0`'s after it, so it needs a special case. the "sub"-possibility is where the number can be either any one or two digits *OR* it can be a `1` followed by either a `0` or a `1`, then any other digit.

For both cases, the "`.` followed by digits" is optional, but if a `.` is present, there must be an appropriate number. In the case of less than 120, the digits can be any digits (including all `0`'s), while in the case of `120`, there can only be `0` characters.

Finally, if you want to require or allow a currency or other symbol before or after the number, you'd put in in like this:

```
^[$£]?((\d\d?|1[01]\d)(\.\d{1,2})?|120(\.0{1,2})?)[€%]?$
```

...where the `[$£]?` placed before the number is either U.S. Dollars or Great British Pounds Sterling, and the `[€%]?` is Euros or a percent symbol

To accept something like `USD` or `GBP` (common abbreviations for currency when symbols are hard to enter or store), you'd add an alternation like this:

```
^((\d\d?|1[01]\d)(\.\d{1,2})?|120(\.0{1,2})?)(USD|GBP|EURO)$
```

If you need support for some other types of number decorations, let me know what they are!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**
This one should work, although it may be better to just check the size of the number one you get one back:

```
/^(\d{1,2}(\.\d+)?|1[01]\d(\.\d+)?|120(\.0+)?)$/
```

Comment: See the 0 - 120 range part of the question. Your regex is unbounded above ie 999999999999999999999999999 matches.

Comment: @rich.okelly: Fixed, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a number between 0 and 120.00

Does that mean that 99.999 is valid or invalid?

Regex isn't really the right tool for this job, however...

`^((1?[0-2])?|\d{0,1})\d?(\.\d{1,2})?$`

Will validate that it starts with 1 in the hundredth spot (or nothing).
Then a 0,1 or 2 in the 10's spot if there is a 1 in the first spot.
Or it can start with any number in the 10s spot.
Then there has to be a digit.
It can then optionally contain a decimal with 1 or 2 digits after it.

So the following tests show just how hard this can be.

- FAIL: -1
- PASS: 0
- PASS: 0.0
- PASS: 10.00
- PASS: 12
- PASS: 99
- FAIL: 999
- FAIL: 999.12
- PASS: 88.1
- FAIL: 12.123
- PASS: 101.12
- PASS: 120
- PASS: 120.00
- PASS: 120.01 <-- WRONG still
- FAIL: 120.001
- PASS: 123 <-- WRONG still

You're much better off using proper tests like if x >=0 and x <=120 than a regex

A working regex solution will require a regex twice as long, and include lookahead/behind assertions and other complex regex fun.

Comment: Not twice as long, and no lookaround required - unless you have some commentary on why the other two answers are somehow not sufficient?